# How to write different script for Debug and Release Builds Xcode IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I am integrating crashlytics for android and ios apps for android using build flavor we can give separate organization key but in ios debug and release scheme i need to run different script because i need to provide different keys to that project.

```
script

    "${PROJECT_DIR}/Fabric.framework/run" 834343231341432432432432432408497cdbfa13ceb728b296e1c595557bb8c389a33693f150f
```

Comment: [`Target`](https://www.appcoda.com/using-xcode-targets/) and [`Build configuration`](https://medium.com/practical-ios-development/some-practical-uses-for-xcode-build-schemes-and-build-configurations-swift-e50d15a1304f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many options for build confg in iOS as well depending on your project.

You could use configuration files  : 
[xcconfig](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/xcconfig_guide.html)

- 1 : Create a new xcconfig file ( base.xcconfig) with the following :

  `KEY = YOUR_DEBUG_KEY`
- 2 : Create a release config file ( release.xcconfig) :

  `KEY = YOUR_LIVE_KEY`
- 3 : Set the newly created files in project settings :

[image]

- 4 : In the Build Phase :

  `"${PROJECT_DIR}/Fabric.framework/run" ${KEY}`

Another simple way to do it ( if something needs to be changed in the code itself) :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   // debug config
#else
   // release config
#endif
```

Comment: i want to run different script based on debug and release schemes like android gradle flavors

Comment: Your script will be run as a build phase ?

Comment: yes  in this script for debug i give different key for release i give different key
    
        "${PROJECT_DIR}/Fabric.framework/run" 834343231341432432432432432408497cdbfa13ceb728b296e1c595557bb8c389a33693f150f

Comment: Although I wouldn't recommend doing so for just a simple thing, you can add another target called QA which has it's own build phases - there you can change the key.

Comment: 2017-08-02 20:38:43.170 uploadDSYM[1888:62158] Fabric.framework/run 1.6.2 (205)
error: Fabric: Configuration Issue

Fabric API key not valid. Your Fabric run script build phase should contain your API key:
./Fabric.framework/run INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY INSERT_YOUR_BUILD_SECRET  i am getting this error

Comment: Make sure you add the xcconfig files to the appropriate targets. And execute the command as "Run Script" in the build phase.
Working fine with fine with no additional steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your sheme to add a script for each configuration.

EDIT: You click on your scheme -> Edit Scheme... -> Click on Build Arrow -> Pre/Post actions -> + -> New Run Script Action

Comment: that is only i am looking where is that configuration

Comment: Added details in my response